# Firebase - How to order items?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a very simple list-based android app.

Is there a easy way to order objects and sort them by date?
My goal is to show the last added item on top of the list.

I've already tried with a client-side solution but it's not efficient.

At the moment i'm using this json data model:

```
{
    id:"",
    name:"",
    body:"",
    date:"date here"
}
```

Does anyone have and idea on how to solve this?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: And how are you achieving it currently client-side?

Comment: I'm developing in java (with Android Studio) and i'm achieving that by ordering the object by date (here's the object model {id:"",name:"",body:"",date:"date here"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must must use `orderedByChild` by the key of the date you'd like to order the children by. You can then observe the `Value` or `ChildAdded` event type of this query to retrieve the children in ascending order of date. To have the most recent first, you must reverse the objects manually client-side. Otherwise, you could prepend a `-` symbol to all the dates and handle it client side.

Comment: Can you write a short example of it, just so i can understand how to implement this feature?

Comment: My intent is to order 100 items and every time a new one is added.